# alert shows undefined in javascript when passed value form aspx.cs page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
 string locationName = "Mumbai";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Type.GetType
    ("System.String"), "addScript", "PassValues(" + locationName + ")", true);
```

in javascript my code contains

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function PassValues(locationName)
            {
             var txtValue = locationName; 
             alert(txtValue);
            }
</script>
```

Here the alert shows undefined instead of "Mumbai"

Comment: Welcome to SO, please use {} tool box button to mention your code parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting single quotes around your variable in the code behind.  Without them, the browser thinks you are passing in a variable named Mumbai.  What you really want to pass is the string 'Mumbai'.  You get the message, 'undefined', because there is no variable named Mumbai in the client side code.

```
 string locationName = "Mumbai";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Type.GetType
    ("System.String"), "addScript", "PassValues('" + locationName + "')", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

this works perfectly for me:

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string locationName = "Mumbai";

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Type.GetType("System.String"), "addScript", "PassValues('" + locationName + "')", true);
        }
    }
}
```

**Default.aspx** ( auto generated as content page from Visual Studio 2010 when created the new web application for testing )

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function PassValues(locationName) {
        var txtValue = locationName;
        alert(txtValue);
    }
</script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Welcome to ASP.NET!
    </h2>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to quickly remove your problem, you can simply use **inline ASP.NET**, to quickly run your application:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function PassValues(locationName)
        {
           var txtValue = locationName; 
           alert(txtValue);
        }
        PassValues('<%= locationName %>');
</script>
```

But, the problem is, your code is rendered in browser as:

```
PassValues(Mumbai);
```

This means that JavaScript tries to find a variable called **Mumbai**, and since it won't find it, the **undefined** message would be displayed. Therefore, you should correct your code as:

```
"PassValues('" + locationName + "')"
```

Comment: Then simply put a `debugger;` line at the start of your method `PassValues`, and debug your JavaScript in Firefox (using Firebug).

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the parameter

Change:

```
"PassValues(" + locationName + ")"
```

To

```
"PassValues('" + locationName + "')"
```

Comment: Is there a reason for why you are explicitly setting the type as a typeof "System.String"?

Answer (score 1):

You missed the quotation to pass as string in your `PassValues` javascript function

```
 string locationName = "Mumbai";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Type.GetType
    ("System.String"), "addScript", "PassValues('" + locationName + "')", true);
```

Comment: Please make sure that your method `PassValues` is above the javascript injected.